# Facebook iPhone application: root view animation style

Tags: ios, facebook, homescreen

I'm working on an application that has the same layout as Facebook. I have several icons on the home screen and would like to to make my viewController appear like when one of the icons are tapped.

Any idea on how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to make a view appear in the standard way when the icon is tapped? ie how to make a button which is an image

Or

are you asking how to make the view expand out like they do in the facebook app?

If your are asking the first one, you need to drag on a button in interface builder, then select it, in the button attributes window, in the first tab, in the 'type' drop-down (which is default to rounded rect), choose custom. then set either the image or background to your image (see whatever looks better). You can then link it up like a normal button with an IBAction.

If you are asking the second question, how do you make the views expand out and shrink back, then check out my tutorial:

[How to make expanding/shrinking views on iPhone SDK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJJgUqCH0w&feature=PlayList&p=E97B882FB8C8C0D6&index=0&playnext=1)

Adam